# On the click of button in ng-repeat giving wrong value on alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Below is my code to present XML data in the form of HTML table using AngularJS in which with every recode a button generated called "Delete Request"

HTML code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Email ID</th>
                    <th>Device Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="detail in details" align="center">
                    <td>{{detail.EmployeeID}}</td>
                    <td>{{detail.EmployeeName}}</td>
                    <td>{{detail.EmailID}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="getID()" class="btnDelete">Delete Request</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

XML data which is in HTML table

```
<UserDetail>
  <Detail>
    <EmployeeID>124578</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeName>suresh</EmployeeName>
    <EmailID>suresh@xyz.com</EmailID>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <EmployeeID>587458</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeName>Vivek</EmployeeName>
    <EmailID>vjain@xyz.com</EmailID>
  </Detail>
</UserDetail>
```

AngularJS code:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('myDB.xml')
            .then(function (response) {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                $scope.details = [];
                var data = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
                $scope.details = data.UserDetail.Detail;
                $scope.getID = function () {
                    var myID = $(".btnDelete").closest('tr').children('td').eq(0).text();
                    alert(myID);
                }
            });

        });
      </script>
```

Now the problem is what I'm facing that it is giving only first record(Employee ID) on the click of button even I click on 2nd record button still it is giving me first record(Employee ID) value in my alert. So please help me what should I do with that it gives corresponding record value in alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just  pass emp id in `getID(detail.EmployeeID`) and no need to use jquery selectors to get the  emp id.

**html**

```
<button ng-click="getID(detail.EmployeeID)" class="btnDelete">Delete Request</button>
```

**js**

```
 $scope.getID = function(myID) {
   console.log(myID); // you can get current clicked emp id 
 }
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u1xhrkhn/)**

Comment: Welcome dude @VIVEKJAIN

Answer (score 0):

**You should not do like this because AngularJS philosophy is to focus on model.**

Balachandran answer is fine for you and you should use that approach but if you still want to do then

```
<button ng-click="getID($event)" class="btnDelete">Delete Request</button>
```

and in your controller function just get the refrence of button like following.

```
$scope.getID = function ($event) {
    var elmRef=$event.target;
    var myID = $(elmRef).closest('tr').children('td').eq(0).text();
}
```

I did not check it but as far as I think this will work fine.